# Using bower modules with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I am new to Webpack and I started with Webpack2. I can't manage to use require or import of modules from bower_components folder. Is it possible to do so and if it is can you provide me an example or something.

This is my webpack.config file:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can configure [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) to also look in `bower_components`.

```
resolve: {
  modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules']
}
```

This will first look into `bower_components` and if it can't find the module it will look into `node_modules`. If you don't inlcude `node_modules` you won't be able to use packages installed from npm.

Comment: I am getting this error 

"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bigvideo' in '/Users/Sempa/Desktop/PersonalWeb/app/assets/javascripts/vendor'
 @ ./app/assets/javascripts/vendor/main.js 3:15-34"

And this is my code (screenshot)

`resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "app/components"), "node_modules"]
    },`

My bower modules are installed under '/app/components/'

Comment: Are they in `app/components` (what you have configured now) or in `app/components/bower_components`? The latter makes more sense, so you would need to configure the correct path.